# How to get dovecot to use postfix mailbox?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I try to get postfix and dovecot up and running.

I have a little problem with the mail-box path that connects both.

**Postfix**

```
virtual_mailbox_base    = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydom.org
```

This creates a file

```
/var/vmail/mydom.org/sam
```

as an mbox-file if I send to sam@mydom.org. The sent mail is inside of that file.

So far - so good.

But in dovecot I have this for a virtual user.

```
sam@mydom.org:{PLAIN}mysecret:5000:5000::/var/vmail/mydom.org::userdb_mail=mbox:~/%u
```

That creates

```
/var/vmail/mydom.org/sam@mydom.org/inbox
```

after successful login.

So my POP3-client finds always an empty mailbox. If I copy the postfix-mailbox to the inbox-file, then POP3 gets the message.

How do I get dovecot to use the postfix-mailbox or postfix to use the dovecot-file?
I tried several settings in dovecot but I did not get it going to use the posfix-file as it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I adapted vmaps of Postfix to match the dovecot-requirements.

Needed to

```
postmap vmaps
```

to make it work in Postfix - only a restart is not enough.